# Creating table with current date plus 30 days after current date

Tags: mysql, database

Can someone help me create a table with the date being equal to current date plus 30 days. Is this right?

```
CREATE TABLE SAMPLE 
( datetoday DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT current_datetime(),
  dateafter30days DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT current_date(+30)
);
```

The logic is for example there is a subscriber that registered now so it will be recorded on the database and the expiration of his registration is after 30 days.

Meaning date of registration and date of expiration..

Many Thanks

Joey

Answer (score 4):

You may use calculated (and optionally persistent) field for this:

```
CREATE TABLE YourTableName
(
Subscriber INT PRIMARY KEY,
IssueDate DATETIME,
ExpireDate AS DATEADD(DAY, 30, IssueDate)
)
```

Comment: @DatabaseAdmin Best thank is always upvote and accepting the answer 8-)

Answer (score 1):

```
create table SAMPLE
(
   SUBSCRIBER_ID    INT Primary Key,
   REGISTER_DT      DATETIME NOT NULL,
   EXPIRE_DT        DATETIME NOT NULL
)
```

you can update expire date when register for new user as follow.

```
 INSERT INTO SAMPLE(SUBSCRIBER_ID,REGISTER_DT,EXPIRE_DT)
    VALUES (1,GETDATE(), DATEADD(DAY,30,GETDATE())
```

Comment: Hi i tried that already,, but is it possible to put the value on the create script as default values like this  create table SAMPLE
(
   SUBSCRIBER_ID    INT Primary Key,
   REGISTER_DT      DATETIME NOT NULL default (1,GETDATE() ),
   EXPIRE_DT        DATETIME NOT NULL default DATEADD(DAY,30,GETDATE()) )

Answer (score 1):

Yes, here you try. When new subscriber data is inserted, registere date is current date, expire date is 30 days after current date. Your insert sql statement, don't need to mention these two columns (REGISTER_DT,EXPIRE_DT), these two will be updated auto on inserting statement.

Based on following table structure, your insert statement should be

```
INSERT INTO SAMPLE (SUBSCRIBER_NM) VALUES ('John');
```

-- table creation statement

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SAMPLE](
        [SUBSCRIBER_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [SUBSCRIBER_NM] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
        [REGISTER_DT] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_SAMPLE_REGISTER_DT]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
        [EXPIRE_DT] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_SAMPLE_EXPIRE_DT]  DEFAULT (dateadd(day,(30),getdate())),
     CONSTRAINT [PK_SAMPLE] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [SUBSCRIBER_ID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a table and a trigger on insert 
**Table **

```
create table test 
(
sub_id int primary key,
issueDate datetime,
expDate datetime
)

CREATE TRIGGER test_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON `test` 
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.issueDate = IFNULL(NEW.issueDate,NOW()),
NEW.expDate= TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,30,NEW.issueDate)
```